# CentOS: yum update Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo

Tags: linux, centos, networking, yum, proxy

I am trying to do `yum update` but I'm getting the following error.

I have exported `http_proxy` & `https_proxy`

Have added proxy settings in `/etc/yum.conf` like:

```
proxy=http://10.44.208.10:8080
proxy_username=username
proxy_password=password
```

Error is

```
[root@cp-hj-dev-gs02 ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 407"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I am able to `curl` and `ping google.com` without any problems.

If this matters, my password contains `&`and I have kept it as it as in both configuration.

I am using CentOS 6.5 and `uname -a` shows output

```
Linux cp-hj-dev-gs02 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: what does `env | grep -i proxy` have to say?

Comment: The [HTTP 407 response](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.8) is "Proxy Authentication Required", which indicates that yum hasn't correctly authenticated to your proxy. Did you add the username and password to the exported http_proxy? "If this matters, my password contains &and I have kept it as it as in both configuration." I ran into a problem on RHEL (which is similar to CentOS) a while back where certain utilities could not handle passwords with ampersands. Have you tried changing the password temporarily to rule this out?

Comment: @Ryan Correct! It was company proxy creds were changed and they were blocking those repos. Thank you very much for the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two problems

1. The proxy credentials I was using were changed by the team. So they were incorrect at the time I was using them.
2. Company proxy was blocking those URLs.